# Why does this Rewrite rule throws a 500 inside .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

on a server with PHP and mod_rewrite I have the following .htaccess in the document root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .(rewriteme)$ rewrite.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I make a request to `http://theserver.com/arewriteme`, I get a 500 internal server error.

But on my local system, the rule above works great and the script `rewrite.php` is executed (it simply echoes `It works!`) when I request `http://localhost/arewriteme`:

```
<?php echo "It works!"; ?>
```

Why do I get a 500 error on the remote server though? I don't have access to the global Apache configuration, but I am sure the module gets loaded as `phpinfo() shows:

[image]

I looked at different questions here on SO, but basically all say that it the error is due a syntax error within `.htaccess` (which is not my case because the rule works on localhost).

So, maybe, there's something in the global configuration of Apache? Maybe the creation of `.htaccess` is somehow denied? Could it be possible?

Thanks for the attention.

EDIT: I was able to contact the hosting provider and they told me that they disabled `.htaccess` throught the whole htdocs directory. How did they do that so that the server thrown a 500 Internal Server Error? `AllowOverride None` inside the main Apache won't do the job because in this case Apache would simply ignore the rules inside the .htaccess but won't throw any error...

Comment: What do your actual logs say on the server?

Comment: Is it a typo `rewriteme` != `arewriteme`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's what the `.` is for in the regex.

Comment: @Mike I knew I should avoid anything to do with rewrite rules.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Haha I hear ya. Regex isn't my forte either. I plug most things into regex101.com just to be sure.

Comment: @Mike Roger that good buddy

Comment: Your rule is fine. You need to check Apache error.log to know why 500 is coming.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great, but the thing is that I don't have access to the server logs. That's why I asked here on, maybe someone faced the same issue...

Comment: Please, checkout my edit, I was able to contact the hosting provider and they told me that they disabled .htaccess throught the whole htdocs directory. How did they do that so that the server thrown a 500 Internal Server Error? `AllowOverride None` won't do the job...